# warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘xyz’

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

I'm getting a number of these warnings when compiling a few binaries:

```
warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strcpy’
warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’
```

To try to resolve this, I have added

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

at the top of the C files associated with this warning, in addition to compiling with the following flags:

```
CFLAGS = -fno-builtin-exit -fno-builtin-strcat -fno-builtin-strncat -fno-builtin-strcpy -fno-builtin-strlen -fno-builtin-calloc
```

I am using GCC 4.1.2:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704
```

What should I do to resolve these warnings?

Comment: Can you post the code that fails?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have permission to repost this code.

Answer (score 290, accepted):

In C, using a previously undeclared function constitutes an implicit declaration of the function. In an implicit declaration, the return type is `int` if I recall correctly. Now, GCC has built-in definitions for some standard functions.  If an implicit declaration does not match the built-in definition, you get this warning.

To fix the problem, you have to declare the functions before using them; normally you do this by including the appropriate header. I recommend not to use the `-fno-builtin-*` flags if possible.

Instead of **stdlib.h**, you should try:

```
#include <string.h>
```

That's where `strcpy` and `strncpy` are defined, at least according to the `strcpy`(2) man page.

The `exit` function is defined in **stdlib.h**, though, so I don't know what's going on there.

Comment: Thanks, I have about 20 .c files to clean up and missed adding some headers.

Comment: Solved my issue when trying to compile a C program to check virtualization type (Xen HVM/KVM/VMware/Bare Metal), cool! Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

**In the case of some programs, these errors are normal and should not be fixed.**

I get these error messages when compiling the program phrap (for example).  This program happens to contain code that modifies or replaces some built in functions, and when I include the appropriate header files to fix the warnings, GCC instead generates a bunch of errors.  So fixing the warnings effectively breaks the build.

**If you got the source as part of a distribution that should compile normally, the errors might be normal.  Consult the documentation to be sure.**

Answer (score 11):

**Here is some C code that produces the above mentioned error:**

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  exit(1);
}
```

Compiled like this on Fedora 17 Linux 64 bit with gcc:

```
el@defiant ~/foo2 $ gcc -o n n2.c                                                               
n2.c: In function ‘main’:
n2.c:2:3: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in 
function ‘exit’ [enabled by default]
el@defiant ~/foo2 $ ./n 
el@defiant ~/foo2 $
```

To make the warning go away, add this declaration to the top of the file:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Comment: Read the question; he's already mentioned adding stdlib.h. But that's only good enough for the exit, not for the string functions.

Comment: Although it did help me out here.

Answer (score 7):

I met these warnings on `mempcpy` function. Man page says this function is a GNU extension and synopsis shows:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <string.h>
```

When `#define` is added to my source before the `#include`, declarations for the GNU extensions are made visible and warnings disappear.