# warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'function xyz' [enabled by default]

Tags: c, gcc

Why is it when compiling source code with the Wall option enabled, that calling certain functions produces warnings such as
`warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'strcpy' [enabled by default]|"`

I looked up the function and added its header and the warning went away. What are the pros and cons of adding a header when (apparently) it's not needed?

Comment: You should consider upgrading to a C99 compiler. With GCC it is easy: just download the latest version and compile with `-std=c99`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘xyz’](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/977233/warning-incompatible-implicit-declaration-of-built-in-function-xyz).

Comment: In addition to the one mentioned above,  many of the results of [searching for this message on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=warning%3A+incompatible+implicit+declaration+of+built-in+function+is%3Aquestion) could also be considered duplicates.

Comment: @Lundin I know this sounds stupid but I'm developing in a different machine than latter will be compiling. Since I didn't install GCC on the other machine I'm not sure which version it has. How do I check which version (for example C99) it is?

Comment: You don't necessarily need to update GCC. Just enable warnings and pay attention to them.

Answer (score 8):

There are no "pros and cons". You must always include the header before using functions declared therein. You should consider it an outright error to do otherwise. The fact that C allows "implicit declarations" is a historic relic that should never, ever be used in actual code.

Answer (score 3):

When you forgot to include the header, The compiler assumes that the function has a return type of `int`, this is called implicit declaration. The advice would be don't use it, as it's error-prone and it's removed since C99.

Answer (score 0):

Because all strcpy,strcat are built in function .It directly look up the file string.h