# calloc() and realloc() compiling issue

Tags: c

I'm learning c not really fully understand everything, i have this example code i gat from a book. The Topic is the usage of calloc() and realloc().I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and the gcc compiler. I checked on the syntax in the code and is just the same as in the book didn't make any mistakes. So what i think the problem is, is how to write the code so that the compiler understands it the way it needs it. For that i do not have the experience to figure that out. I have more error outputs if needed.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void main(){
    double * memptr;
    memptr = (double *) calloc(100, sizeof(double));
    if (memptr == NULL){
        printf("\nNicht genuegend Speicherplatz!");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("\nSpeicher fuer 100 double-Variable Ok!");
    memptr = (double*) realloc(memptr,125);
    if(memptr ==NULL){
        printf("\nNicht genuegend Speicherplatz!");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("\nSpeicherplatz auf 125 Variable vergroessert!");
    free(memptr);
    printf("\nSpeicher wieder freigegeben!");
}
```

#### Error messages:

```
*bei84.c: In function ‘main’:
bei84.c:7:22: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘calloc’
[enabled by default]

memptr = (double *) calloc(100, sizeof(double));
                  ^

bei84.c:13:21: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘realloc’
  [enabled by default]
  memptr = (double*) realloc(memptr,*125);
```

Comment: That's odd... `calloc()` and `realloc()` are defined in `stdlib.h` which you have included.

Comment: Could you show us how you are compiling the source code as well?

Comment: This is not the answer but you have logical error: `realloc(memptr,125);` must be `realloc(memptr,125 * sizeof (double));`

Comment: I would guess the problem comes from the actual code not including stdlib at all, and the code shown here isn't a 100% copy paste. Otherwise, wouldn't gcc whine about line 6 rather than 7?

Comment: Just an FYI an earlier answer explains why you generally get this warning.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/977233/warning-incompatible-implicit-declaration-of-built-in-function-xyz.. however in your case you seem to have included the correct header file.

Comment: btw. i tried compiling and executing your code.. just a copy paste, and it worked.. so nothing wrong with the code itself. I think it could be more with linking or the way your platform is setup

Comment: gcc bei84.c -o bei84 @ Bill

Comment: @codias: Could you upload to gist.github.com (or anywhere really) the output of `gcc -E bei84.c`?

Comment: I can compile and run this code precisely as shown here without any warning or error. Thus I believe it to be an fault in the OPs system and not a code problem at all, therefore off topic.

Comment: When you program in C (not C++) you should never cast the return value of `malloc`, `realloc`, or `calloc`.

Comment: my problem is not the code but how to rewrite so that the compiler gets it

Comment: @codias: The problem is that we can't find any issues with your code. It should compile and run successfully.

Comment: Check that you include the intended header files. Do you have any `stdlib.h` other than the compiler's in your search path? You get the answer with `gcc -E myprogram.c`. BTW: The output *must* show the prototype if you have included the intended file. Else `#include <malloc.h>`.

Comment: I am able to compile and run the code in Ubuntu 14.04. how are you compiling it ?

Comment: Somehow your compilation is not finding the prototypes, even though this post has correctly used `#include<stdlib.h>`.  Suspect you prototype exists in some other header file.  Check your compiler documentation about its location.

Comment: let me try the things you have said we be back

Comment: @Bill https://github.com/codias/calloc-and-realloc-compiling-issue/issues/1

Comment: @codias: Yeah. That's not super helpful because it's being parsed by markdown. If you use [gist.github.com](http://gist.github.com) instead, it won't do a markdown pass over it.

Comment: sry @Bill https://gist.github.com/codias/705aa59cb42f4ac8c9e9

Comment: That's not the entire output. There is more at the beginning.

Comment: To be more explicit, assuming you are using gcc 4.8.2 (I know you're using gcc 4.8.x), you've skipped 1402 lines.

Comment: `void main()` is non-standard. You should not cast the result of `malloc`. If you want 125 doubles, `realloc(memptr,125)` is wrong. You can check where your includes come frome by adding `-H` to the gcc command line.

Comment: Your program [compiles and runs](http://ideone.com/HQoS3p) despite the small problems I pointed out in another comment. It is safe to assunlme that either your gcc installation is broken, or you are not compiling the program you think you are compiling.

Comment: hi ppl thanks for the advices, it still ain't working. I have included the malloc.h header files and removed all the casts infront of the function and compiled it with codeblocks still getting errors coming from my <stdlib.h>.    https://gist.github.com/codias/77bf488056c6098db074

Comment: codeblock is on a wiindows 7 machine

Comment: I have reinstalled Ubuntu no changes still not working.   gist.github.com/codias/10b7d526ce3340cfdfa3 this is what i get after gcc -E bei84.c

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning, say `#include <malloc.h>`, that may clear up some issues.  Also, you can put spaces between lines of C code; the compiler doesn't care, and it makes it SO MUCH EASIER TO READ!

And when you use `realloc`, you do not need the `(double *)`, `memptr` is already a `double *` and it is understood how the return is cast into a `double *`.

Comment: No, OP should identify and fix a problem with his system, rather than swipe it under the carpet.

Comment: i have reinstalled ubuntu and tried the code on a different maschine.