# warning: implicit declaration of function ‘sendto’

Tags: c, warnings

I have following problem:

```
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘sendto’
```

on line in variable `outputCounterByte`:

```
outputCounterByte += sendto(server_socket, outputBuff, offSet, 0, (struct sockaddr*) remote_addr, server_addr_len);
```

I don't understand this, where is a problem? 
OutputCouterByte is on value 0, and other variables are defined. I have included all headers(prototype of function).
In other functions it is working.

Comment: `I have included all headers`..don't be so sure about that. :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘xyz’](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/977233/warning-incompatible-implicit-declaration-of-built-in-function-xyz)

Answer (score 1):

You need to include

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
```

to provide the function prototype.