# Comparing char to string - C

Tags: c

so I've viewed multiple threads here now on this site about comparing my char array to a string or something of that sort with things like `strcmp` and `strstr` however whenever I compiled it, I got the error:

```
warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'strstr' [enabled by default]
```

and honestly I have no idea what this means. I'm relatively new to C...

So here's my code:

```
int main(){

  FILE * fPointer;
  fPointer = fopen("test.txt", "r");

  char action[10];
  char num[100];
  char* s;

  while(fscanf(fPointer, "%s", action) != EOF){
    s = strstr(action, "JUMP");
    if(s != NULL){
      puts("Jump");
    }else{
      puts("Don't Jump");
    }
  }

  fclose(fPointer);

}
```

I've tried a few other things, but none of them worked out. My text file has a bunch of actions:

```
JUMP 4
CRUNCH 7
SITUP 8
```

and other similar things like that. I wanted the while loop to scan for each action, and then compare it to whatever to see if action is = to "jump" etc, etc, and if it is, then scan the number to tell me how many times to do each action.

Can someone help me with this? Thanks so much!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The code as such lacks the headers.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/977233/warning-incompatible-implicit-declaration-of-built-in-function-xyz

Comment: Any time you use a library function, read the documentation (`man function_name` if you're on a Unix-like system). It should tell you how to call it and, most importantly in this case, what header you need to `#include`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't included the proper header.

```
#include <string.h>
```

Comment: God I'm dumb... Thanks -.-